# Smaller apk after upgrade Visual studio

Tags: android, apk, visual-studio-2019, upgrade

I updated Visual studio 2019 from 16.5.1 to 16.8.3
If I generated APK in older version, the size was 94 MB, now is 55 MB. Why?

The new version causes app crash.

Answer (score 3):

Xamarin.Android now has the entry `android:extractNativeLibs="true"` set by default, which causes smaller APKs since Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.8.

You can get the opposite behavior with an AndroidManifest.xml such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.myapp">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <application android:label="myapp" android:extractNativeLibs="false" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you, but now is APK size 70 MB. There must be something else in the new version...

Comment: @MartinNebeský check the [releasenotes for last versions](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/releases)